# PHP Apache Authorization Header

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I'm having trouble retrieving the Authorization Header sent by Angular to Wamp Apache PHP.

Here is a snapshot of my chrome dev tools:

[image]

After a lot of research I was able to get the **$_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]** variable to appear in **PHP** by adding any of those to the **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]
```

The following variations **didn't** work for me (PS: they may be viable for other people):

```
CGIPassAuth On

SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

My issue is that the Header is now present in PHP but **EMPTY**.

[image]

An example of API endpoint being use

[image]
Here is my setup:

- PHP 7.2.1
- APACHE 2.4.35
- WAMP 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try $_SERVER['Authorization']